# What would this register contain after

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

I can't seem to figure out what `eax` contains after this peice of assembly:

```
mov     edi, [edi+4]
lea     eax, [edi+88h]
```

With `edi` pointing to a class

Comment: Assembly has classed? (or: are you telling us everything?)

Comment: Does your class have virtual members? @Kobi; probably a c++ disassembly, or stopped before the assembly.

Comment: @Kobi It is a disassembly of a C++ shared object. Of course there isn't really any classes in assembly but it makes it easier for me to understand

@roe Yes, it has virtual members

Comment: kotarou3 - I realize that. I tried to imply you should supply as much information as possible, to get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Load Effective Address](http://siyobik.info/index.php?module=x86&id=153) gets the actual address of the reference. For some arcane reason, the symbolic assembly is written as if it references the content of edi+88h, but what the instruction actually does is loading the **value** of the edi register plus the constant 088h (equivalent to  `mov eax, edi; add eax, 088h`). I doubt edi+4 is a function pointer: more likely, it's a vtbl pointer or an array.

Comment: Wait, isn't a class similar to a vftable? Well actually, edi points to vftable and edi+4 points to a function in the vftable

Comment: If there is multiple inheritance involved, the compiler may implement it via multiple vtable pointers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). [edi+4] may be loading a secondary vtable, in which there's a function at offset 088h. Perhaps you should say why you're so sure edi+4 is a function pointer?

Comment: Actually, as I think about it more... It might not be a pointer to a function

Answer (score 0):

A long shot, since I know nothing about your class, but here goes anyway.

Do you have multiple inheritance? Perhaps `edi+4` is the second virtual table, and `[edi+4]+88h` is a function pointer you wish to call? Or depending on your compiler, it might be that the virtual table is located at `+4`, in either case `eax` contains the address of the virtual function to call.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the use of `edi`, it probably ends up pointing to a memory location, but `lea` isn't always used like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Useful_side_effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov     edi, [edi+4]
lea     eax, [edi+88h]

    edi points here after 'mov'
    .
    xxxx....................
    |                      ^
xxxx....                   eax points here after 'lea'
^
edi pointed here before 'mov'

char* edi;
void* eax;

edi = *(char**)(edi+4);
eax = edi+0x88;
```

It looks like some record is just getting accessed there.